# Wikipedia's definition of "Adverbial"

Tags: prepositional-phrases, syntactic-analysis, adverbials

On the Wikipedia page for Adverbials, it says [emphasis mine]

> In grammar an *adverbial* is a word (an [adverb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverb)) or a group of words (an [adverbial phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_phrase) or an [adverbial clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_clause)) that **modifies** or tells us something about the sentence or the **verb**.

Further down the page it says that “in the water” is an *adverbial complement* in:

> John put the flowers in the water
>   <sub><sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial#Types_of_adverbials_that_form_sentence_elements)</sup></sub>

But in the sentence above, *“in the water”* is not a modifier of the verb *put*.  It is a complement and a prepositional phrase because it begins with the preposition *in*. Why is it called an adverbial? If we remove the complement we are left with:

> *John put the flowers.

This sentence is clearly incomplete.  If we use an adverb instead of *in the water* we have:

> John put the flowers **here**.

The sentence makes sense, *here* is an adverb, and it tells the listener “where” the flowers are *put*. According to Wikipedia an *adverbial* is either an adverb or a group of words, so is *here* also an adverbial?  Considering its position within the sentence, does *here* also function as a complement? If I add further information is it an adverbial phrase, or something else?

> John put the flowers **here in this vase**.

The subject of the clause is John, the verb is *put* (past simple), *the flowers* is the direct object, and *“here in this vase”* is: What?

**Questions**

1. Why does Wikipedia say ***in the water*** is an adverbial?
2. Is  *“here”* also acting as a(n) (adverbial) complement?
3. Is ***in this vase*** the modifier of the object (the flowers) or the verb? How do I tell?
4. What effect does the adverb, ***here***, have on the sentence?
5. Is ***here in this vase*** an *adverbial phrase*, or an *adverbial complement*. Is it called something else?

---

<sub>This post was adapted and inspired  by an edit (now deleted) in  the question: [Adverbial phrase](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266755/adverbial-phrase). For those who wish to see the original "edit" see the meta post [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7063/shall-we-reopen-this-helpful-question).</sub>

Comment: One downvote cast after one minute. Is it for lack of research? For a question that is  not useful? Because  it is unclear?

Comment: Because an adverbial is "a word or phrase functioning like an adverb."

Comment: @Noah so any word that isn't an adverb, but acts like one, is an adverbial. So what's the difference between an adverb and an adverbial?

Comment: Part of the problem, I think, is that "put" is often part of a phrasal verb. "John put the flowers" doesn't work, and seems searching for a preposition. Sometimes, though, it can work on its own: "John put the argument". if you change to a slightly different verb, your construction seems to work ok: "John placed the flowers"; "John threw the flowers". What's happening here with "put", I don't know. Would your question be the same with a change of verb?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes.  Please read this for more details. http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv279.shtml

Comment: @Noah you're welcomed to post an answer.

Comment: This would probably be better at [linguistics.se].

Comment: @curiousdannii   No, I want this question here. I'm not a member of linguistics, I'm not a linguist, I'm not a grammarian. EL&U has tons of questions that can be answered by looking up the answer in a dictionary. I don't believe this question is particularly arcane.

Comment: @curiousdannii are you the downvoter? Did you downvote because I asked more than one question? How can I possibly limit this post to one question? They're all interconnected.

Comment: @Mari it's rude to accuse people of downvoting, but FYI no I didn't downvote this question. And I'm not saying it's offtopic here, but that you'd get better answers at linguistics.se. These sites are all about learning. You don't need to be an expert to ask them questions, that's the whole point of asking questions!

Comment: @curiousdannii  I'm sorry, but often the first vote I receive on my questions is a downvote. Then I usually get a number of upvotes, which of course I never question! :) But to get a downvote in the space of one minute means that the downvoter has a strict criteria which he or she follows, and I was wondering what it was. So, sorry again. I wasn't angry, I was defending my five questions embedded in one post!

Comment: @Mari-LouA was smacked by a DBDV (drive-by down-vote), a plague upon  this forum.  If you ask someone, "Are you the downvoter, you lazy, contemptible ignoramus?" then *that* would be rude.  I don't find it rude to ask politely for the purpose of understanding the objection and possibly improving the question.

Comment: Some questions are like children... you just want to protect them:)

Comment: Just a guess at answering question 1: Wikipedia says *in the water* is adverbial because Wikipedia is an unreliable and not necessarily truthful source when not cited.

Comment: @JakeRegier none of the answers posted so far seem to uphold this opinion. Well, we'll see how this post goes.

Comment: 'In grammar an adverbial is a word (an adverb) or a group of words (an adverbial phrase or an adverbial clause) that modifies or tells us something about the sentence or the verb.' (1) Does Wikipedia intend 'tells us something about' as a clarification of 'modifies' or an alternative? (2) Does it subscribe to the analysis that modifiers and complements are  disjoint entities? How does it define 'complement'? ...

Comment: (3) In 'Or he is deaf', the word 'or' tells us that an earlier (contrasting) proposition has been made in an earlier sentence: it tells us something about the sentence. (If you want to argue that this isn't idiomatic, substitute _And_) Yet I've never seen it classed as an adverb. (I'd call it a contrastive sentence-connector here, obviously closely related to the coordinator usage.) (4) In 'He is here', can we realistically say that _here_ 'modifies' be? Wikipedia's treatment is simplistic and inadequate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth (1) Wiki would probably say it's an adverbial. (2) I don't know. It's not something I have ever read (3) Wikipedia does say adverbs is a *catch-all*. But I wouldn't class "or" as an adverb either. (4) I would hesitantly  repy *yes*. What do think of the answers posted? Are they too simplistic? Could I have asked "better" questions? Is there something I missed?

Comment: Why isn't anyone upvoting these answers?!?

Comment: The question is highly interesting and important. But until we (ie the Profs)  get terminology sorted out, and deconstruct the adverb morass once and for all, I can't see how it can be properly answered. I think @deadrat's first bullet point is a good place to start a sensible analysis of adverbial function. Complications soon arise (is 'here' fulfilling an adverbial role in 'I am here'? How do we handle deleted forms such as 'She's playing with the girl next door'?)

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry about the misery-guts examples)

This topic is not covered by the [BBC analysis](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv279.shtml) or Wiki, or other introductions, It is not the verb which is being qualified in these examples, but a Noun which in this case is the subject.

*The fiddler on the roof wears an afghan coat.

The group behind the bike shed carry butane lighters.*

... But **To begin at the beginning**.
There are clear cut ***Adverbial Phrases:***

> Breathlessly, painfully, hopelessly, Einstein ran for the 'bus.

There are clear cut ***Adjectival Phrases***:

> Panting, aching and despairing Groucho ran for the 'bus.

There are hybrid ***Adjectival Phrases*** in which **the Verb-Noun** (or Participle) is qualified by an **Adverbial Phrase**:

> Breathing with difficulty, aching in every limb, and rapidly losing
>   hope Casandra ran for the 'bus.

And there are indeterminate ***Prepositional Phrases*** which could be taken as qualifying the noun or the verb (leading to analytical absurdities like "Adverbs qualify verbs, adjectives, and **nouns**,")

> Out of breath, in pain, without hope Frankenstein ran for the bus.

Some of the terms used here cross boundaries:

In a functional analysis "Adjectival," "Adverbial" are appropriate.
In syntactical analysis "Prepositional Phrase" is useful.
These shouldn't normally interfere with each other any more than a typographical description, 'In Bold,' or a rhetorical description, 'Exemplar,' would add something without confusion.

Comment: That's interesting! I think I almost understand it too :) Thank you so much. I will cast my votes later, I think I need to see what others have to say.

Comment: The superset of adjectival and adverbial is a modifier.

Comment: @curiousdannii.  Thanks: that is progress.  Is there discussion of ambivalent modifiers?

Answer (score 1):

I found this [discussion](http://papyr.com/hypertextbooks/grammar/cl_ad&ac.htm) helpful.

1. Why does Wikipedia say **in the water** is an adverbial?  Because the function of the prepositional phrase serves to tell us one of the traditional adverbial things about the verb.  Which things are generally time, place, or manner.  The cite (and site) above gives a baker's dozen of  expanded categories of adverbial action.  Note that the same terminal phrase can be adjectival in a different sentence:

> John bought the flowers **in the vase**.

"In the vase" tells us which flowers.

2. Is “here” also acting as a(n) (adverbial) complement?  An adverbial complement completes the sense of the verb and appears in two forms -- in reference to the *subject*:

> The *flowers* are **in the vase**.

or in reference to the *direct object*:

> John put the *flowers* **in the vase**.

Deleting the complement leaves defective sentences "The flowers are" and "John put."

With "here in the vase" you may say that you've got a double complement, with "in the vase" in apposition to "here."  The deletion rule doesn't work:  you may delete either the belt or the suspenders and still have a workable sentence.  But together, I think they still may form a complement.

3. Is *in this vase* the modifier of the object (the flowers) or the verb? How do I tell?  If the phrase is a complement (i.e., the verb is incomplete without the phrase), then you know it modifies the verb.  Otherwise, you have to look at the meaning.
4. What effect does the adverb, here, have on the sentence?  It depends on whether you bind "here" to "in the vase."  If you do, then it's an adverbial complement.  If you don't, then "here" is free to wander as a simple adverb:

> **Here**, John put the flowers in the vase.

Perhaps narrating a scene from a movie.

> John **here** put the flowers in the vase.

It's this John sitting next to me who brought the bouquet.  Or even

> John put the {flowers **here**} in the vase.

These flowers right here, vocal emphasis on the word *here*.

5. Is here in this vase an adverbial phrase, or an adverbial complement. Is it called something else?  See above.

Comment: Thank you, that's a really clear explanation. But I'll wait a bit before voting. Thanks again!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Intriguing questions on an interesting topic.  I'd give it at least the rest of the day for other other contributions.

Comment: In 'John bought the flowers in the vase', 'in the vase' may be an adverbial of manner. Compare 'He bought all the plates at the lower price'; contrast 'John bought the flowers, but left the vase'